# Why don't I see my task in the Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, task, scheduler

Few years ago, I created a powershell script and ran it in the Task Scheduler every time the user is logging on. The script is still running. But now, when I look for it in the task scheduler I don't see this task even it still runs every time that I log on.

How can I find the script in the task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Task Scheduler both as yourself, *and* as an administrator (Run as administrator), even if you are an administrator. See if that shows any differences.

Comment: I tried to run as administartor and I still don't see it.